# Не работает ссылка для открытия файла

Tags: html

Есть такая конструкция:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
  <div class="home-hover navigation-slide">
    <a href="/files/111.pdf">
      <img src="images/PDF.png" style="width:20%">
    </a>
  </div>
  <a href="/files/111.pdf">
    <span style="color:white;">DOWNLOAD PDF</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Но ни одна из ссылок не работает при клике. Если нажать правой кнопкой мыши и выбрать открыть в новой вкладке, то открывается необходжимый файл, в чем проблема?

Comment: При клике на ссылку в консоли браузера вылезает ошибка: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at goToByScroll (script.js:187)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (script.js:206)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5)
    at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5)`

Comment: Так ошибка-то связанно со скриптом, а не с html.

Comment: Покажите код, как же понять по нескольким строчкам